# Implementing Rate Limiting in asyncio for Remote Calls with QPS Constraints

Tags: python, python-asyncio

**Note: The answer to [Asyncio & rate limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683243/asyncio-rate-limiting)  that uses sleep method is not what I want.**

I'm working with an asynchronous function in Python that performs a remote call, which takes approximately 20 seconds to complete. However, this remote call is subject to a QPS (Queries Per Second) limit imposed by the server: it only allows up to 2 calls per second. Exceeding this limit results in an exception being thrown.

Here's a simplified version of my async function:

```py
async def fun(x: int) -> int:
    # Simulates a remote call that takes 20 seconds to complete
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    return x
```

I've attempted two methods to process multiple calls to this function:

**Method 1: Sequential Await in a Loop**

```py
res = [await fun(i) for i in range(1000)]
```

This approach does not fully use the asynchronous capabilities, as it waits for each call to complete before making the next one.

**Method 2: Using asyncio.gather to Run Concurrently**

```py
tasks = [fun(i) for i in range(1000)]
res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

While this method attempts to run the calls concurrently, it results in exceeding the QPS limit, leading to errors.

I'm seeking a way to effectively use asyncio for making these remote calls, respecting the QPS limit without causing exceptions due to rate limiting. Specifically, I need a mechanism or pattern that allows me to:

1. Ensure that no more than 2 calls are made per second.
2. Use asyncio to manage the asynchronous execution efficiently.

Certainly, I could manually craft a for loop and introduce some sleep functions within a sliding window to adjust the rate, but this approach feels somewhat inelegant and less in line with Pythonic principles. **The answer to [Asyncio & rate limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683243/asyncio-rate-limiting)  that uses sleep method is not what I want.**

Is there a built-in feature in Python's asyncio library or a recommended pattern for adding a rate limiter to manage QPS constraints in such scenarios?

Comment: You can use an asyncio.Semaphore to do what you want.
```python3
# Create a semaphore to limit concurrent calls
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(qps_limit)
async with sem:
    res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Comment: @VoNWooDSoN he wants to limit them in time, not in concurrent execution.

Comment: Yeah, the question was marked as deleted, so I quit trying to answer.

Comment: @VoNWooDSoN Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to reopen this question, since the duplicate one is not what I want. I don't want to use for-loop + sleep method.

Comment: There is also an answer with semaphore that seems to do what you want: "Ensure that no more than 2 calls are made per second". It didn't work for you?